# PHP - removing mulitdimensional array elements but keeping the values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
[place0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [foods] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 1390794747912097
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 1620226508192375
                            )

                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 399421393563221
                            )

                        [3] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 1611940965687753
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[place1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [foods] => stdClass Object
            (
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 699879946787937
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 1434488970184270
                            )

         )

            )

    )
)
```

How would I extract the IDs and sort them into a new array, or just remove [place0]->foods->[data] and [place1]->foods->[data] and merge them?
Ideally I don't want to loop through each part of the array but is that the only way?

Comment: Post code you have tried, and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = array_merge_recursive($a->foods->data,$b->foods->data);
$c = array_map(function ($&a) {return $a=$a->id;},$c);
```

one way to rome ...

Comment: change array_merge_recursive  to array_merge only!